# Why is only one of the below codes right when they both work properly?

Tags: c++

I have to display all odd integers from `1` to `20`:

My teacher says that this loop is wrong because it has no logic:

```
int i;
for (i=1;i<=20;i=i+2)
{
    cout<<endl<<i;
}
```

According to him, this is right:

```
int i;
for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    if (i%2!=0)
    {
        cout<<endl<<i;
    }
}
```

Why does he say that the first loop is wrong even though they both give the same result?

Comment: Your teacher's a moron.  The first one is clearly better, though it's fair for the teacher to ask you to write the second as a learning exercise.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong

Comment: Actually, they're both wrong because of the `getch`. That makes it very difficult to use the program in a script or if the output is redirected to a file. (Most likely, this was an attempt to keep the output visible if the program was launched with a "temporary console" that was set to close automatically as a way to avoid having to learn how to properly launch a console program. If you're going to use a platform, learn the basics of how to use it rather than buggering up your programs to work a bad environment setting.)

Comment: Second example is more readeble, because of cheking  if (i%2!=0), than first

Comment: Depending on the wording of the exercise, you may be asked to do something less efficiently as an understanding point.  So you'd have to give us the *exact* wording of the problem AND the *exact* wording of why he wanted you to give the second solution and not the first to decide if he's a "moron"...or if you're not following the specific directions of the assignment.  Hard to imagine such an assignment, but people asking questions on SO aren't always "reliable witnesses"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Your version is clearly better in every possible way :). The version of your teacher loops 20 times, while your version only loops 10 times. It is 100% more efficient (even if it gets optimized away by the compiler, then there is no difference).

*Note: you don't even need the `=` in the comparison, because it will never be `20`, only less.*

---

If you want to you can see the difference in the assembly generated (non-optimized):

**Your version**

```
main:
                                   ; Initialization omitted
.LCFI1:
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $1, -4(%rbp)       ; Initialize 'i' to 1
        jmp     .L2                ; Jump to compare statements
.L3:
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax     ; Copy 'i' to register1 (for function call)
    
        ; Omitted call to std::cout to output 'i' and '\n'
        
        addl    $2, -4(%rbp)       ; Add 2 to 'i'
.L2:
        cmpl    $20, -4(%rbp)      ; Compare 'i' to 20
        jle     .L3                ; Jump only if 'i' < 20
        movl    $0, %eax           ; Reset (cleanup)
        leave                      ; Leave
```

**His version**

```
main:
.LCFI1:
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $1, -4(%rbp)       ; Initialize 'i' to 1
        jmp     .L2                ; Jump to compare statements
.L4:
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax     ; Copy 'i' to register1
        andl    $1, %eax           ; XOR 'i' with 1 (same as 'i' % 2)
        testl   %eax, %eax         ; Compares 'i' to 'i'
        je      .L3                ; Continue loop by jumping if 'i' == 0
                                   
        ; Omitted call to std::cout to output 'i' and '\n'
.L3:
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)       ; Add 1 to 'i'
.L2:
        cmpl    $20, -4(%rbp)      ; Compare 'i' to 20
        jle     .L4                ; Jump only if 'i' < 20
        movl    $0, %eax           ; Reset (cleanup)
        leave                      ; Leave
```

As you can see your version has far less instructions than his version, so yours runs faster, in the non-optimized code.

Here are the benchmarks for the non-optimized version

```
Version | Time
You     | 0s
His     | 0.015625s
```

And here for the optimized (compiled using `-O3`)

```
Version | Time
You     | 0s
His     | 0s
```

In the end, there is no difference, because the compiler is quite good at optimizing such loops.

## *Disclaimer*

The above assembly was generated by g++ 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14, using the following command: `g++ -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm foo.cpp`

Comment: I'd call this 100% more efficient. It goes from X efficiency to X*2 efficiency, which is an increase of a whole X.

Answer (score 0):

The first code example does not determine if a number is odd. It uses pre-existing knowledge to print all off numbers in the 1-20 range. The pre-existing knowledge is that you already know that the numbers 1, 3, 5, ... are odd numbers, you just print that information. The second example goes over all numbers 1-20 and calculates/determines if any number in that range is an odd number. Meaning, if it's not divisible by 2 (hence the % 2 operation) then it's an odd number. That's what your teacher is saying.

Comment: This is a good observation.

Comment: what a load of rubbish. Your suggestion uses pre-existing knowledge that if a number is not divisible by 2 then it is odd. How is that different to pre-existing knowledge that adding 2 to an odd number produces the next odd number?

Comment: That's a good observation too.